# Handling votes through forms

Tags: django, forms, function, django-templates, voting

I installed [django-vote](https://github.com/shanbay/django-vote) which has a simple API:

```
review = ArticleReview.objects.get(pk=1)

# Up vote to the object
review.votes.up(user_id)

# Down vote to the object
review.votes.down(user_id)
```

I've got a Car page with multiple reviews that I wish to vote. I tried:

```
<form action="{% url 'reviews:review-vote' review.id %}" method="GET">
    <button type="submit" name="vote-up"></button>
    <button type="submit" name="vote-down"></button>
</form>
```

URL:

```
url(r'^(?P<review_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.review_vote, name="review-vote"),
```

View:

```
def review_vote(request, review_id):
    if request.GET.get("vote-up"):
        review = Review.objects.get(id=review_id)
        review.votes.up(request.user.id)
    return redirect("car", {"make": review.car.make, "years": review.car.years})
```

This doesn't execute the vote and doesn't redirect to the Car page. I'd like to implement the voting API in my template, without reloading the page if possible.

Any suggestion or feedback will be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: are you getting the value `"vote-up"` in the backend?

Comment: Yes, it works in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the key `vote-up` or `vote-down` which one is there in the `request.GET`

```
<form action="{% url 'reviews:review-vote' review.id %}" method="GET">
    <button type="submit" name="vote-up"></button>
    <button type="submit" name="vote-down"></button>
</form>
```

and in the views try this.

```
def review_vote(request, review_id):
    if "vote-up" in request.GET:
        review = Review.objects.get(id=review_id)
        review.votes.up(request.user.id)
    return redirect("car", {"make": review.car.make, "years": review.car.years})
```

Comment: Figured out the problem: There's an overlapping in my URL's, so my form's action attribute directs me to another view function. That's why votes aren't registered.Thank you for your reply.